# Reading a text file using stdin then traversing through multiple arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, text, stdin

I got a text file that is a single line of a string. For example:

> I’m John

I need to read the file using stdin then traverse each characters into multiple arrays where each row shifts to the left by one character:

> row1 = [I, ‘ , m ,  , J , o , h , n]
>
> row2 = [‘ , m , , J, o , h, n , I ]
>
> row3 = [m ,  , J , o , h, n, I , ‘ ]
>
> row4 = [,  , J , o , h , n , I , ‘ , m]
>
> ...
>
> rown = [n , I , ‘ , m ,  , J , o , h ]

It is important to note the length of the arrays and number of arrays I create are variable that are dependent on the length of the string from the text file (n*n). In this case it would be 8*8 characters, so I need to create 8 arrays with 8 length each. 
Any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know how to read *one* line into an array?

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

I would read the data into an `std::string`.

I'd create an `std::vector<std::string>` to hold all the results.

I'd use the vector's `push_back` member to append a string to the vector.

Then I'd use `std::rotate` to rotate the string by one character.

I'd repeat appending and rotating for as many characters as the string contains.

Comment: I'd rather store only the original string only and apply the transformation only when accessing elements, but somehow I consider it as too lame to write an answer ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: wouldn't quite answer exactly what the OP asked, but certainly a solid possibility in many situations.

Comment: @Leoid9: I suppose I could, but I hesitate to provide a turn-in ready solution to what looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jerry is correct and gives a crisp solution to your problem. 
You can perhaps have it better using `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` to hold the data and doing something like:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        data[i][j] = input[(i+j)/len];
    }
} while (i++ < len) // len is 8 in your case
```

Comment: your code will work without modifications for a `std::vector<std::string>` (supposed you add the missing parts)